# Creating a scatterchart in powerBI using percentiles as the x and y axis

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a scatterplot in powerBI that shows X axis as length of relationship of all clients up to the selected fiscal year and month banded in quintiles and Y axis is the total revenue of all clients up to the selected fiscal year and month banded in quintiles. The values on the chart should be YTD percentage revenue and number of clients.

I have a table called customers, where I have created the relationship length quartile in a measure using this formula -

```
Relationship Quintile = 
VAR ThisVal = MIN(Customer[Relationship Length])
RETURN
IF (
    ThisVal > 0,
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE(Customer[Relationship Length]),
        VAR FirstQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[Relationship Length], 0.2), Customer[Relationship Length] > 0)
        VAR SecondQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[Relationship Length], 0.4), Customer[Relationship Length] > 0)
        VAR ThirdQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[Relationship Length], 0.6), Customer[Relationship Length] > 0)
        VAR ForthQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[Relationship Length], 0.8), Customer[Relationship Length] > 0)
        RETURN
            IF (
                ThisVal <= FirstQ, 1,
                IF (
                    ThisVal <= SecondQ, 2,
                    IF (ThisVal <= ThirdQ, 3,
                    IF (ThisVal <= ForthQ, 4, 5)
                )
            )
    )
)
)
```

I also have a measure where I've created revenue quintile using this formula -

```
RevenueQuintile2 = 
VAR ThisVal = MIN(Customer[TotalLineTotal])
RETURN
IF (
    ThisVal > 0,
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE(Customer[TotalLineTotal]),
        VAR FirstQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[TotalLineTotal], 0.2), Customer[TotalLineTotal] > 0)
        VAR SecondQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[TotalLineTotal], 0.4), Customer[TotalLineTotal] > 0)
        VAR ThirdQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[TotalLineTotal], 0.6), Customer[TotalLineTotal] > 0)
        VAR ForthQ = CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(Customer[TotalLineTotal], 0.8), Customer[TotalLineTotal] > 0)
        RETURN
            IF (
                ThisVal <= FirstQ, 1,
                IF (
                    ThisVal <= SecondQ, 2,
                    IF (ThisVal <= ThirdQ, 3,
                    IF (ThisVal <= ForthQ, 4, 5)
                )
            )
    )
)
)
```

The measures work in a table, but only if I include the customerID.
[image]

I've created a number of customers calculated column -

```
NoofCustomers2 = count(SalesOrderHeader[CustomerID])
```

But if I add it to the table and remove customerID I see nothing.

[image]

Can someone please assist with how I can create this chart. I want to show how many customers (and then % as well) for each quintile range, I'm obviously summing by the wrong thing somewhere. Thanks